# Get Color From HSL Values in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colors, hsl

I just want to know how to get a Color() Object or a Hex Color Value ( uint ) from HSL values in flash.´

The idea behind the HSL is, that i can map vaues from a range ob anything, to the range of the Hue ( 0 - 360 ) and get the coresponding color.

Further I want to control the Hue value seperate from the "lightness" or "brightness" value.
the saturation will allways be 100%.

The "base" of my code looks like this:

```
function getHSL( var Hue, var Saturation, var Lightness ) {
// Hue = 0 - 360, Satturation = 0 - 100, Lightness = 0 - 100

    // DO THE MAGIC

    return color // as3 Color() object
}
```

So if I would have this funktion, i could just call it in a `for( i=0; i<360; i++)` loop where `i` would be the Hue to create a rainbow color spectrum.

i already have done some `map()` functions to easily handle "streching" color spectrums ( like bars that are not exactly 360 px long.

So guys if you have any idea how i could generate Colors from HSL values in as3, please tell me.

**SOLUTION UPDATE**

```
function getColorFromHSL( h:Number, s:Number, v:Number ):Array {
    var r:Number = 0;
    var g:Number = 0;
    var b:Number = 0;
    var rgb:Array = [];

    var tempS:Number = s / 100;
    var tempV:Number = v / 100;

    var hi:int = Math.floor(h/60) % 6;
    var f:Number = h/60 - Math.floor(h/60);
    var p:Number = (tempV * (1 - tempS));
    var q:Number = (tempV * (1 - f * tempS));
    var t:Number = (tempV * (1 - (1 - f) * tempS));

    switch(hi)
    {
        case 0: r = tempV; g = t; b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q; g = tempV; b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p; g = tempV; b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p; g = q; b = tempV; break;
        case 4: r = t; g = p; b = tempV; break;
        case 5: r = tempV; g = p; b = q; break;
    }

    rgb = [Math.round(r * 255), Math.round(g * 255), Math.round(b * 255)];
    return rgb;
}
```

Comment: you need to convert hsl to rgb then pack rgb to hex. googling for "as3 hsl to rgb" should get you there. also have a look at mr.doob's [color utils](https://code.google.com/p/mrdoob/source/browse/trunk/libs/net/hires/utils/ColorUtils.as)

Comment: you should add your solution as an answer, not as an edit to a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Josh Whizzle's [ColorMathUtil.as](http://www.therealjoshua.com/code/flex/calico/src/com/flashfactory/calico/utils/ColorMathUtil.as).  It has everything you need, and then some.

Comment: well, thx but i allready found it. however i'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Link appears to be out of date